# Can failure a compareTo?

Tags: java, comparator

I have an application that converts some text files into other test and csv files (for each 3 text files I generate a text file and a similar csv file). It is ordering some camps according to a `compareTo` method, the difference between the text files and the cvs files are that in the text files I have for example 27 camps and in the csv files only 25, but the other information is the same, the two that I obten have had the some order.

For example in the original text file I have: Name, surname, telephone number, zip code and a number of identificaction.

In the text files that the application returns I have: Name, surname, zip code and number of identification.

In the csv files I have: Name, zip code and number of identification.

The problem is that I must reorder by the zip code with the next code:

```
public int compareTo(Comunicado otro) {
    int cod1=Integer.parseInt(this.codigoPostal);
    int cod2=Integer.parseInt(otro.codigoPostal);
    if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod1=0;
    else if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod1=1;
    if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod2=0;
    else if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod2=1;
    if(this.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod1=2;
    }
    if(otro.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod2=2;
    }
    return cod1-cod2;
 }
```

Is there any possibility that the two files that I return have different order?

I have change my code adding the next lines:

```
   public int compareTo(Comunicado otro) {
    int cod1=Integer.parseInt(this.codigoPostal);
    int cod2=Integer.parseInt(otro.codigoPostal);

    if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod1=0;
    else if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod1=1;
    if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod2=0;
    else if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod2=1;

    if(this.codigoPostal.equals(otro.codigoPostal))
    {
        if(this.codicoCliente.compareToIgnoreCase(otro.codicoCliente) == 0) 
        {
            return this.codicoCliente.compareToIgnoreCase(otro.codicoCliente);
        }
    }

    if(this.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod1=2;
    }
    if(otro.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod2=2;
    }
    return cod1-cod2;

 }
```

Is this enough to sure that there isnt problems?

Finally i have solved my problem with the next code:

```
    if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod1=0;
    else if(this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod1=1;
    if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("28") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("28")==false)
        cod2=0;
    else if(otro.codigoPostal.startsWith("08") && this.codigoPostal.startsWith("08")==false)
        cod2=1;

    if(this.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod1=2;
    }
    if(otro.codigoPostal.equalsIgnoreCase("00000")){
        cod2=2;
    }

    if(this.codigoPostal.equals(otro.codigoPostal))

    {
        int i = this.codicoCliente.compareTo(otro.codicoCliente);
        if (i != 0) return i;
    }


    return cod1-cod2;


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing (unless I've misundstood your code) - if the two post codes start with the same two digits then your compareTo says they have the same ordering. So you could end up with the postcodes in two different orders. For example 08123 and 08321 could end up as:

```
08123
08321
```

or

```
08321
08123
```

Ideally, your compareTo should not be able to return 0, if you want to avoid this. To test if this resolves the issue, try:

```
return ((cod1-cod2)==0 ? (this.codigoPostal.compareTo(otro.codigoPostal)) : (cod1-cod2));
```

instead of your current return statement. NOTE I'm not saying this is nice-code, I suspect the whole method could be refactored, but want to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks, when i have in the original txt some people wiht the same zip code, i need that in the two files that i return, the two must have the same order. is it necesarry then that i do other comparation to avoid the problem? i have try the apliccation with a lot of txt, and ever i have the same order, even if there are too many people with the same zip code. In the apliccation first of all must appears the people with zip code 28***. the the people with zip code 08*** and finally the people with other zip code but, that appears by the logical order of the number.

Comment: I've edited my answer with some revised code. Let me know if it resolves the issue

Comment: Hi, i think that with your code i can find a problem because i use the cod1 and cod2 as an int and i think that with that return it is impossible to use cod1 and cod2 as an int.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't mean to compareTo cod1 and cod2 , but the postal codes. The idea is, if compareTo thinks the two postal codes have the same order, then it should fall back to comparing the two postalcodes as strings. I am assuming that everyone has a different postal code (although they might start with the same two digits). If some people have identical postal codes, then you will need to sort them on another field, as well. Answer edited

Comment: A lot of people can have the same zip code. Then i need ever other fild to sort? Even if a do the two return files with the same process?? But, how i do if my compareTo must return first the people with zip code starting by 28 and then the people with zip code starting by 08?